# Unable to upload a VM from VMware Workstation to Esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-workstation

I have been trying to upload a VM from VMware workstation to VMware ESXI server (Esxi 6.7 A01)

I edited the hardware compatibility of the VM to ESXI 6.5 and created a clone.

When trying to upload the VM to esxi server i get the following error:

**Upload failed: Invalid configuration for device '0'.**

[image]

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Sukhvir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .vmx files of ESXi and Workstation are not compatible. The recommended way to migrate a VM is to use the [vCenter Converter](https://www.vmware.com/de/support/support-resources/pubs/converter_pubs.html).

Don't let the name fool you, it's a free product.

Comment: Vcenter converter is very handy for a lot of v2v and p2v conversions. If you don't want to go to the easy route though you could create an empty container and then replace the vhd file with the one from your instance, but depending on what selection you use you may run into a fault of not compatible drivers. I mean just because it's possible doesn't mean you should do it this way. You would also have to do it via the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the following device as I don't think it compatible with vSphere.

- USB Controller
- Sound Card
- Printer

Comment: I echo this recommendation, trim the VM settings back removing anything that can added after import into ESXi. 3D graphics acceleration was another gotcha for me. I couldn't use vCenter Converter as I'm not running Windows.